# How to check if category/tag exists in Jekyll?

Tags: if-statement, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to achieve a post header like in the example below:

```
8/18/2018 | Tags: foo, bar
```

In order to do that I need to make sure tag exists, otherwise `| Tags:` section waste space in untagged post.

After searching the web, I tried this statement:

```
{% if post.tags != nil %}
    <b>Tags:</b>
    {% for tag in tags %}
        <a href="{{site.baseurl}}/tags/#{{tag|slugize}}">{{ tag }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But every statement always returns true whether tag declared in front matter.

What should I do to hide the label?

Comment: Well what *is* that value if there are no tags? Given that the iteration was presumably succeeding, I'd guess an empty list, not nil.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Guess I was just too desperate to try every possible value. Originally, I tried  {% if post.tags %}, then {% post.tags = "" %} I double checked everything but no luck. So I ended up trying nil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{% if post.tags != nil %}` is always `true` because `post.tags` is an `Array`.

If this array is empty, `{{ post.tags | inspect }}` will output `[]`.

To test if this array contains something, you can use :

```
post.tags != empty
```

This code does the trick :

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
{% if post.tags != empty %}
  <b>Tags:</b>
  {% for tag in post.tags %}
      <a href="{{site.baseurl}}/tags/#{{tag|slugify}}">{{ tag }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```